# jQuery.ajax loads image late?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a site that loads and injects html into a page for editing.  The first thing I do when I load the html is that I check it for images and do some processing with them.  It shouldn't require that they be all the way loaded - just their attributes - for me to process them.

There is literally one folder on the site where when I load html from that folder and get it back, it doesn't load the images properly.  If I log the returned responseText, I can see the image as an element within.  For example:

```
var ajax=$.ajax({
    url:url,       
    data:data,
    accepts:'html',
    dataType:'html',
    success:function(data){
      console.log($(data)) // -> logs jQuery HTML object to Chrome console w/ images
      console.log($(data).find('img')); // -> []
      window.d=$(data); // global object that I can parse in console and extract img
      });
```

The following gives the same problem:

```
    var ajax=$.ajax({
      url:url,
      data:data,
      accepts:'html',
      dataType:'html'
     });

     ajax.then(function(data){
      console.log($(data)) // -> logs jQuery HTML object to Chrome console
      console.log($(data).find('img').toArray()); // -> returns []
      window.d=$(data); // global object that I can parse in console and extract img
     });
```

The processing I do on the images isn't complicated.  I just parse their source and store it in a global object.

How can this possibly be?

**EDIT**:  I altered it a little bit to more accurately reflect the case.  Also, keep in mind that this particular ajax call works in all other cases accept this on folder (maybe five diff. html files) : so I would imagine the error is in some way derived from something to do with the way the image loads ? That just doesn't make any sense though.

**EDIT 2**:  Per request, here is an example of html returned when the errors occur.  As you can see on the second line, there is an `img`:

```
<h2>About Frank A. ..., M.D.</h2>
<img class="fltleft" width="200" height="243" alt="Dr. ..." src="http://zjq.metapsychology.org/imgs/research_pub/img1.jpg">
<br>
<p>... is an Honors graduate of Stanford University who later pursued graduate studies in philosophy at Cambridge University in England. He received his medical degree from yale University, and completed a psychiatric residency at Stanford University Medical Center in the early 1970s.  ....</p>
```

I abbreviated the output.  But there is an image there.

Comment: `console.log($(data).find('img')); // -> Throws error ` should never throw an error. did you mean it logs 0 elements?

Comment: I'm not sure, first I tell you my answer here and if it was true I post it for others. This is because you did not set dataType in your ajax request. Could you please add dataType:"html" in yout ajax request and tell me the result?

Comment: @AliMasudianPour Do you think it is parsed as string? He says it is parsed as HTML?!? But could be. ;)

Comment: @AliMasudianPour the default dataType is text, which with the way he's using it in his code would work just as well as "html". I don't think that's the answer.

Comment: Addendum to my first comment: it should never throw an error, assuming the first console didn't throw an error.

Comment: @KevinB Actually default is intelligent guess. But it could be, that the parsing fails, since the failure is only on this one page, and there may be something which leads jQuery to parsing wrong.

Comment: That still doesn't explain why the first line doesn't error and the second does. if it were a datatype problem, he wouldn't even be in the success callback.

Comment: @KevinB You are right. It could be because of not containing ';' the line before it.

Comment: Haha, yeah, with the automatic insertion of `;` you never know. But if it actually errors, it would be nice to see the error. ;-)

Comment: @KevinB Might not be a "problem" for jQuery, but he says it is HTML, so all good, hmmm

Comment: @AliMasudianPour - What I posted here was pseudocode.  I do set the dataType to HTML.

Comment: @KevinB - Your right - it is not an error.  I will edit question.  Returns `[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your images aren't descendants of the root element within data, they ARE root elements in data. use filter instead.

```
console.log($(data).filter('img'));
```

and to find both root AND descendants so it'l work in both cases, use this:

```
console.log($(data).find('img').addBack().filter('img'));
// find all images in data, add back the root elements, then filter to only images.
```

Comment: Now That is really weird.  There are different folders.  When I use find, the top level folders work, and some - but not all - of the second layer folders work.  When I use filter, the top layer folders fail, and the second level folders work fine.  Now I think your answer will probably lead me to the source, but, I can't figure out why.  Why would the top level folders return the data differently?  Or maybe you can't tell without seeing much more?

Comment: What is a folder? aren't we talking about html?

Comment: The code pulls HTML from files in folders.  The fact that it works when pulling code from some folders and not others & which folders work reverses when using find vs filter seems odd, no?  Just to make it more clear - each folder has a slew full of HTML fragment files - the data is pulled from them.  The fragments are structured the same and there is no root element or wrapper for any of them.

Comment: Can you show an example html output from one such request? i'm guessing that would explain everything.

Comment: I think it would be too long to put here, I will edit it into my answer.

Comment: That particular img would be accessible with filter.

Comment: Well.  I fixed it with the following (though it doesn't make any sense).  `var fn=$(data).filter('img').length>0 ? "filter" : "find"; $(data)[fn]('img')...//process code;`  A bit more hackish than I'd like, but this is an old project, and I'm ready to put it to bed.  You definitely pointed me in the right direction.  Thanks

Comment: Would you like this better? `$(data).find("img").addBack().filter("img")`

Comment: I'm calling this the correct answer, because it ended up leading to the completion of this problem.

Comment: .addBack adds the original selection to the current selection, which is why it results in selecting all descendants AND root images.